# javascript, zooming in and out of a table

Tags: javascript

Basically what I want to do is when I scroll up, zoom into my table, making it larger and when I scroll down, zoom out of the table, making it smaller.

Here is the js

```
    var mainGridW = $("#mainGrid").width();
    var mainGridH = $("#mainGrid").height();

    function setupMouseWheel(){
        if (zoomContainer.addEventListener) {
            zoomContainer.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', onMouseWheelSpin, false);
            zoomContainer.addEventListener('mousewheel', onMouseWheelSpin, false); // Chrome
        }else{
            zoomContainer.onmousewheel= onMouseWheelSpin;
        }
    }

    function onMouseWheelSpin(event) { 
        var nDelta = 0;
        if (!event) { event = window.event; }
        // cross-bowser handling of eventdata to boil-down delta (+1 or -1)
        if ( event.wheelDelta ) { // IE and Opera
            nDelta= event.wheelDelta;
            if ( window.opera ) {  // Opera has the values reversed
                nDelta= -nDelta;
            }
        }
        else if (event.detail) { // Mozilla FireFox
            nDelta= -event.detail;
        }
        if (nDelta > 0) {
            HandleMouseSpin( 1, event.clientX, event.clientY );
        }
        if (nDelta < 0) {
            HandleMouseSpin( -1, event.clientX, event.clientY );
        }
        if ( event.preventDefault ) {  // Mozilla FireFox
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        event.returnValue = false;  // cancel default action
    }

    function HandleMouseSpin(delta, x, y) {
        if (delta < 0){ 
            mainGridW = mainGridW/1.10;
            mainGridH = mainGridH/1.10;
            $("#mainGrid").width(mainGridW);
            $("#mainGrid").height(mainGridH);
        }
        if(delta > 0){
            mainGridW = mainGridW*1.10;
            mainGridH = mainGridH*1.10;
            $("#mainGrid").width(mainGridW);
            $("#mainGrid").height(mainGridH);
        }
    }
```

Here is the html

```
<body onload="setupMouseWheel();">

<div id="zoomContainer">
    <table id="mainGrid" height="100%" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"></table>    
</div>

</body>
```

This all works, except one problem... In firefox there is a lag before it will work. When I try to scroll it says "not responding" for a few seconds then after it starts to respond again it will work but very slowly. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is lag because `onMouseWheelSpin` is called repeatedly and too fast. Firefox is not as powerful as webkit browser like Chrome, Safari. To resolve this, you can implement a timer to reduce the work.

```
var timer;
function onMouseWheelSpin(event) { 
    if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
       //your code here
    }, 30);   //delay
}
```

And also `$("#mainGrid")` can be converted to `document.getElementById('mainGrid')` and `.width()` with `.style.width`

When doing animation, native code is always faster than jQuery. By using jQuery, you are trading `write less` with performance.

I think the 2 events you attached above nearly execute at the same time, thus more lag. When you use a mouse wheel, your page is scrolled. Using a `clearTimeout(timer)` will prevent the previous call to be terminated